# How find logical contradictions and redundancies in a list of symbolic expressions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, symbolic-math

Sometimes I have a small number of variables, and I need to compute some result according to the relationships between the variables. So I need to account for all possible relationships between the variables and calculate the result accordingly.

For instance, [a, b] and [c, d] are integer ranges, a <= b and c <= d, [I want to find all possible relationships of [a, b] and [c, d]](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76850067/4), or a, b, c are some numbers, and I want to find the minimum and maximum of them in one function call without using `min` and `max`.

For this purpose, I create all possible n choose 2 pairs, and fill the vacant comparison symbols with Cartesian products of the symbols `'<', '<=', '==', '>=', '>', '!='` of power n choose 2, to get all possible such expressions irrespective of logical consistency and redundancy, and manually process them.

For instance, to find all possible size relationships among a, b, c, I would do this:

```
from itertools import product

relations = [', '.join(''.join(e) for e in zip('abc', triple, 'bca')) for triple in product('<=>', repeat=3)]
```

`relations` is the following list containing 27 expressions:

```
[
    'a<b, b<c, c<a',
    'a<b, b<c, c=a',
    'a<b, b<c, c>a',
    'a<b, b=c, c<a',
    'a<b, b=c, c=a',
    'a<b, b=c, c>a',
    'a<b, b>c, c<a',
    'a<b, b>c, c=a',
    'a<b, b>c, c>a',
    'a=b, b<c, c<a',
    'a=b, b<c, c=a',
    'a=b, b<c, c>a',
    'a=b, b=c, c<a',
    'a=b, b=c, c=a',
    'a=b, b=c, c>a',
    'a=b, b>c, c<a',
    'a=b, b>c, c=a',
    'a=b, b>c, c>a',
    'a>b, b<c, c<a',
    'a>b, b<c, c=a',
    'a>b, b<c, c>a',
    'a>b, b=c, c<a',
    'a>b, b=c, c=a',
    'a>b, b=c, c>a',
    'a>b, b>c, c<a',
    'a>b, b>c, c=a',
    'a>b, b>c, c>a'
]
```

There are lots of logical inconsistencies and redundancies, after manually processing the expressions I get the following 13 logical consistent expressions with the least terms:

```
[
    'a<b, b<c',
    'a<b, b=c',
    'a<b, c<a',
    'a<b, c=a',
    'b>c, c>a',
    'a=b, b<c',
    'a=b, b=c',
    'a=b, b>c',
    'b<c, c<a',
    'a>b, c=a',
    'a>b, c>a',
    'a>b, b=c',
    'a>b, b>c'
]
```

How can I programmatically do this? In other words, given a number of undefined variables, and a list of comparisons among them, how to determine if there will always be logical contradictions between the comparisons for all possible values of the variables involved?

Comment: I don't see the goal of all of this. it's hard to figure out what kind of result you _need_. "SAT checking" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem and for integers, it's "SMT": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories this is college level stuff. I think you'd enjoy taking such lectures.

Comment: or maybe you just want to calculate the union of a set of ranges? the problem description in *this* question seems more abstract than it needs to be. the problem description in your other/linked question seems to be obscured by minutia of the application.